# Automate venv activation when I start a new tab of Debian WSL

Tags: python, debian, windows-subsystem-for-linux, windows-terminal

I'm using WSL 2 to run a Debian. I created a "ansible" on it. The thing I want to do is that when I open a new tab of this Debian, I want to see `(ansible) XXXXX$:`
I tried two things yet.

1. Crontab (But it's not appropriate with how WSL works as I understood it)
2. Trying to modify my target of Debian as `wsl -e source /home/w123183/ansible/bin/activate`
   The tricky thing here is that it's not it doesn't work. It just that the shell closes immediately after it ran.
   I believe that all this shell stuffs and how it is managed is still blurry for me.
   I hope someone will be able to help me and I thank them in advance for that.

Answer (score 0):

That's actually a tough one, but (courtesy [this Unix & Linux answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/294689/432493)), try:

```
wsl ~ sh -c "cat ~/ansible/bin/activate > ~/.tmp_venvrc; cat ~/.bashrc >> ~/.tmp_venvrc; exec bash --rcfile ~/.tmp_venvrc"
```

That creates a temporary rc file from a combination of your:

- venv `activate`
- Existing `~/.bashrc`

And starts bash with it as its rc file.

Worked for me (ironically also using my Ansible python-venv).

Of course, you can script this either on the PowerShell end of things, or in a shell script that you pass in on the `wsl` command-line.

Comment: Quick note since I can't edit right now - Probably better to have the existing `~\.bashrc` before the `activate`. I think there's also a way to do this without the temporary file - I'll edit it in later as well.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I actually find a solution. I just added `"source ~/ansible/bin/activate"` to my .bashrc.
It works as I wanted now

Comment: While that will work, adding it to your startup config directly means that it will *always* run, even if you have a different project you are working on that needs a venv.

Comment: Yeah now I understand, but is was clearly what I needed to do. Thnaks a lot for the tips and the advice concerning commenting and posting here. I'll improve !